# How to reference two projects with the same name (but different assembly name)?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013

### In short:

I have two projects with the same name (different namespaces and assembly output) in my solution. When I add a reference to both projects in another project using VS2013, I get the following error:

> A reference to 'MyProject.Name (path\to\project\old)' could not be
>   added. A reference to the component 'MyProject.Name' already exists in
>   the project.

This worked fine in VS2012.

**Is this an intended change in Visual Studio 2013?**

### Details:

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and in my solution I have two projects with the same name (one contains legacy code). All classes in the projects have different namespaces and the produced assemblies are also different.

When we were using Visual Studio 2012, I could add references to both these projects to another project in the solution. It would even automatically show the path behind both references.

Now that we've moved to VS2013, *everything still works fine*. I only recently noticed that under references, it only shows one of the two projects (without a path behind it). Everything still builds and I can use classes from the other projects. However, when I try to add a reference to the two projects in another project I get the error message.

Obviously, renaming one of the projects would allow me to add them both. At this moment, this is not a desirable solution. Also, having both references in the csproj file seems to work. So I could edit the csproj file manually and add the references (or use VS2012 to do that). This still leaves a confusing situation though as the VS2013 UI doesn't show this.